# Finding critical (fixed) points and stability of system of differential equations? Stuck on one small bit of working. Working shown below

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am working on a question which asks to find the type and stability of critical point to the following system of differential equations:

$y_1'= -3y_1 + 4y_2 $

$y_2'= -5y_1 + 3y_2 $

I worked out that one critical point is when $y_1=\frac{3}{4}$ and $y_2 =\frac{5}{4}$, giving the critical point $(\frac{3}{4}, \frac{5}{4}). $

There's also another critical point when $y_1=0$ and $y_2=0$, giving the point $(0,0)$.

The next part of the working is to calculate the Jacobian matrix, from which you can determine the type (e.g. node) and stability (e.g. stable) of each point.

I know the Jacobian matrix is given by:

$\begin{bmatrix}
-3 & 4 \\ -5 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$

The problem with this is that it indicates that every critical point has the same type and stability (as it doesn't allow for substituting in y1 and y2 values for each point).

I was wondering whether I have made a mistake or if all the critical points have the same type and stability?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: $J$ should be a constant matrix for linear systems! Just calculate the eigenvalues and analyze them. As a side note, the Jacobian
matrix for nonlinear systems is expected to depend on $(x, y)$.

Comment: Excellent, thanks a lot!

Comment: Also note, there was only a single critical point at $(x, y) = (0, 0)$.